# Why are Git log command outputs different when launched from Windows shell and from Python subprocess?

Tags: python, git

If I execute the command `git log --no-walk --tags --reverse` in the Windows shell, I get results such as:

```
commit e83dcf42f2a52183cf21642c7b8deb42961663f3 (tag: my_tag)
Author: an_author
Date:   a_date
```

while if I execute the same Git command from a Python script:

```
subprocess.check_output(['git', 'log', '--no-walk', '--tags', '--reverse'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

I get the following result:

```
commit e83dcf42f2a52183cf21642c7b8deb42961663f3
Author: an_author
Date:   a_date
```

As you can see, the tag information is missing and as you guess, I need it. Is there anything I can do to get the tag information from the Python subprocess.check_output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to parse `git` output, you should use the form of its commands intended for scripting. In this case it means the `--pretty=format:`[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) option. The `%D` specifier provides the ref names pointing to the commit, and of course you need to explicitly specify all the fields you want.

You might also want to use the lower level `git rev-list` command instead of log; it has similar options, but is promised to have stable interface for script use.

Comment: Yup. The convenience commands try to guess where you're going and help you get there, so `git log` notices when it's talking to a terminal and adds default decorations for human consumption. Which is so often exactly what you want that people don't even notice it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Add option [`--decorate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono):

```
subprocess.check_output(['git', 'log', '--decorate', '--no-walk', '--tags', '--reverse'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```